# How to identify the running express.js version in code?

Tags: node.js, express

Can I identify the running version of express.js from within code?

For example, I can use `process.version` to get the Node version, and `process.versions` for the various dependancies.

Is there a way I can do this for Express?

Thanks

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: check `package.json` file and have a look express version inside `dependencies`

Comment: Thanks. However, package.json may or may not be honored by the provider of the Node/Express environment. I want to verify the declared (in package.json) against the actual executing environment.

Comment: use command  npm list express

Answer (score 22):

In order to find the current version of your Express JS, open your terminal and type:

```
npm list express
```

Another way is to open up your codebase and check the **package.json** file where you will be able to see all the packages installed along with its version number.

Answer (score 3):

1. for local package use command npm list
2. for globally installed packages use command npm list -g
3. a specific package by passing its name as an argument use command npm list express

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package.json file to get the Express version.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const package = fs.readFileSync('package.json')
const packageParse = JSON.parse(package)
const expressVersion = 'v' + packageParse.dependencies.express.slice(1)
console.info('Using Express.js ' + expressVersion)
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting the express version you can use

> read-package-json

module. This will give the data of package.json and you can read the value of express version from it.

for more details, you can refer [here](https://github.com/npm/read-package-json)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the answer I am looking for. The content of package.json may not refer to the version of a component which is executing and I wish to validate the executing version of express with the declared version in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the project folder
type the command
**npm list express**
*Note*: On wrong path of project fodder it will show *empty* message.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Using npm list express shows the version and if express is install or not in cmd
below is example:-

```
C:\Users\Aditya Kumar\nodews\modules_node_js\contact_list>npm list express
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
contact@1.0.0 C:\Users\Aditya Kumar\nodews\modules_node_js\contact_list
└── express@4.18.1
```

Answer (score -3):

You can refer to https://www.npmjs.com/ official website.
If I understand well ?
Express is a module comes from NPM so you have to follow that command and install the latest express framework there !

```
$ npm install express --save
```

CQFD welcome !!

Comment: This does not answer the question, Pascal. He'd. like to get the Express version from within his code.

Comment: Op wants to  `identify the running version of express.js from within code?`