# How to find the Express.js Version in vs code terminal

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, npm, terminal

command line code to find the express js version

express js version
Like For Node : node -v

Comment: This answer should help you with this problem! https://stackoverflow.com/a/65092058/19640149

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify the running express.js version in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876357/how-to-identify-the-running-express-js-version-in-code)

Comment: cd into your app directory, `cat package.json | grep express`